# Is there a FileVault alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: encryption, mac

Is there a FileVault alternative for Ubuntu that I can download from the software centre?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encryption of your home folder is supported by Ubuntu out of the box. This is an option in the Ubuntu installer. See: [EncryptedHome community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to encrypt a few files, here are a couple of possibilities:

- [Cryptkeeper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cryptkeeper) allows you to create a directory where all files will be encrypted (the underlying encryption engine is [encfs](http://www.arg0.net/encfs)).
- [Easy Crypt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/easycrypt) allows you to create an encrypted volume, with a storage format compatible with [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).